# Mex with static libraries

Tags: matlab, mex

I am trying to compile the clpfunction from the opti-toolbox in linux. I am able to compile fine in windows and not require any additional libraries, in linux I am using static libraries but when I do ldd clp.mexa64, it still wants .so files. Is there a way to compile that uses static libraries and no dynamic?

Comment: Which so files does ldd indicate?

Comment: I used the command you are referencing and in windows i attached my .lib files fine. in linux, I do the following:  ./configure --enable-static --disable-dynamic --disable-shared --with-pic --enable-static-nss then make then sudo make install

Comment: the file still wants to reference  libCoinUtils.so.3 => not found even though I build with libcoinutils.la and libcoinutils.a